# How to put values into a C# function and get a result?

Tags: c#

I'm sure this will be very easily answered and can be attributed to me being more than a little 'wet behind the ears' with C# but I'm having an issue calling and putting values into a function before then writing the response on screen.

The function and call works perfectly in PHP (where I have a bit more experience) so I think the issue lies more with using the correct syntax in C# than anything else. Maybe I'm still trying to write it with my PHP hat on?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace postcode
{
  public partial class postcode_finder : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Example lat/long values entered below

        Response.Write(distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M"));
    }

    public double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {

        double theta = lon1 - lon2;

        double dist = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(theta));

        dist = Math.Acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == 'K')
        {
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
        }
        else if (unit == 'N')
        {
            dist = dist * 0.8684;
        }

        return dist;

    }

    //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    //::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :::
    //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    public double deg2rad(double deg)
    {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    //::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :::
    //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    public double rad2deg(double rad)
    {
        return (rad / Math.PI * 180.0);
    }

  }
}
```

The error I get says that 'the best overloaded method match for 'postcode.postcode_finder.distance(double, double, double, double, char)' has some invalid arguments'.

Where am I going wrong? Here's hoping someone with a little more know-how can give me a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I wanted to add that C# / .NET / Visual Studio does wonderful things with code comments. Check out "XML Comments" http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/06/understanding-c-xml-comments.html.

XML Comments show in your code (like above) and also show up in neat ways in Visual Studio while coding. You see them now when you mouse over a .NET framework class or method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`"M"` in C# is a `string`, not a `char`; you need to use `'M'`.

The error you got basically says "I can't find a function called `postcode.postcode_finder.distance` that takes parameters of the types you're giving it".

You should've received a seccond compiler error saying `Argument 5: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'` which would have narrowed down the problem further.

Comment: Maybe if the OP is a confessed noob you should explain how the exception message and how it leads you to the answer... And you have. An even more deserved +1 now. ;-)

Comment: Bingo! Told you it would be easy. Embarrassingly so... thanks!

Comment: Didn't get a 2nd compiler error. If I'd have got the one you mention above I'm sure even I would have put 2 and 2 together successfully. Probably...

Answer (score 4):

The error says it all:

> the best overloaded method match for 
>   'postcode.postcode_finder.distance(double, double, double, double,
>   char)' has some invalid arguments

In other words, the compiler can't find a method named `postcode.postcode_finder.distance` with the signature that you have provided.

In C#, a `char` literal is expressed by enclosing a single character in single quotes. A `string` literal is expressed by enclosing characters in double quotes. If you change `"M"` to `'M'` in your code, this error should go away.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 'M' as the last parameter -- this is how you specify a char constant in C#

Answer (score 2):

`"M"` is a `String`, not a `char`. ( because of the double quote).

So the compiler don't accept your call to the function distance that expects a char.

put `'M'` and it should be ok. ( `char` ar between single quotes)

Answer (score 2):

Your method takes a `char` as parameter.
You pass a string (marked with `"`), chars are declared with `'`.
So it should be like: `distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, 'M');`